# Unable to append two dataframes in pandas with same columns length

Tags: python, pandas

This is what I am trying to accomplish
1. There is a master table. So i extracted column 1,2,3 and columns 4,5,6. I need to stack them on top of one another (not side by side).
2. For this, I extracted them into two data frames and tried to append but it does not seem to work. Here is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import html5lib

link = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_telephone_numbering_in_India"
tables = pd.read_html(link)[3]#select the 3rd section which is our table
base=tables.iloc[:, 0:3]
top=tables.iloc[:,3:6]

print(base)
base=base.append(top)
print(base)
```

Here is my output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phWvp.png)
I need the rows to be added to one another. How can I do it?

Comment: this happens because you don't reassign it back `base = base.append(top)`

Comment: Oh sorry. Rookie mistake. Still I need to stack them on top of each other not side by side

Comment: pandas is index aligned , since the column names of `tables.iloc[:, 0:3]` and `tables.iloc[:,3:6]` are not same, this gets appended side by side as you say but with `NaN` for the top dataframe .  what do you want the final column names to be in that case

Comment: @anky I want them to be stacked on top of each other 1198 rows(599+599) and 3 columns.

Comment: i understood that part, i am asking about the final column names, if you want the column names to be same as `base` assign the same to `top` , `top.columns=base.columns` and then do the append or concat

Comment: @anky thanks it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

think you need to use concat instead of append;

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html

Answer (score 0):

When you want to append a 2nd dataframe, you need to reassign it as follows:

```
base = base.append(top)
```